# UserManager Api in apps script

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script

i am trying to execute this function on google apps script

```
        function test()
        {
        var data=UserManager.getAllUsers();

        Logger.log(data.length);
        }
```

It throws an error ' You do not have permission to perform this action '. Can anyone knows how can i get rid of this

Comment: Did you [enable the Provisioning API](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60757) on your domain?

Answer (score 0):

The UserManager lists all the users of a domain using the (soon deprecated) Provisioning API.

Your script needs to run with the authorization of a domain admin to use UserManager. Is it the case ? The error message seems to indicate the contrary.

In addition I encourage you to have a look at the Directory Service, which should soon replace the UserManager : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory.